# opposite of 'git status' command

Tags: git

I use the `git status` command to find out what I changed locally in my git working directory.
But is there an "opposite" of that command?

What I mean is I would like to find out what others have checked in to my remote/tracking branch (I am not sure if remote branch is same as tracking branch, in git) but these changes are not here in my working directory.

Comment: My first thought was, "You want to know *less* about your branch? Try smoking weed or something..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the question "[How to get the changes on a branch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569/how-to-get-the-changes-on-a-branch-in-git)"

```
git log HEAD..branch
```

could be what you are looking for here.

```
        x---y---z---branch
        /
---a---b---c---d---e---HEAD
```

It would return x, y, z. Note: only two dots, not three here: `HEAD..branch`.

As mentioned in this other question:

> This is identical to `git log branch --not HEAD`, and means "all commits on branch that aren't on `HEAD`"

Note: you need a `git fetch` first, in order to update your local copy of a remote branch. Without that, you would not pick any new modification on the remote branch.

---

Note: a [tracking branch](http://book.git-scm.com/4_tracking_branches.html) is a local branch that is connected to a remote branch. When you push and pull on that branch, it automatically pushes and pulls to the remote branch that it is connected with.

When you clone a repository, Git only creates a branch corresponding to the remote's master. For each other branch that exists at the remote that you wish to work on locally, you need to create a local branch to track the remote branch.

A patch could be in the making (June 2009 for the [patch *proposition*](http://lists.zerezo.com/git/msg694246.html)) to add to `git remote` command the '`tracking`' option, with (this is not a *definitive* description, but still a work in progress)

```
git remote tracking <remote> <remote branch>
```

> would show all local branches that track `<remote branch>`, and have `<remote>` as default remote, while

```
git remote tracking <local branch>
```

> would show `<remote>` and `<remote branch>` if `<local branch>` is following remote-tracking branch.

I do not see this feature in the [upcoming Git1.6.4](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/868631) though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for the "git log" command..check the man page [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180272/how-to-preview-git-pull-without-doing-fetch) question in SO may also help