# Is there a "git pull --dry-run" option in Git?

Tags: git, git-pull

Is there such a thing as `git pull --dry-run` to see how stuff will be merged before it messes up my working tree?

Right now I am doing:

```
git fetch origin && git merge --no-commit --no-ff
```

I did not see anything in the man page for 'git-pull' related to it.

To clarify, I just need it in an Ant script for deployment to see if there are conflicts when doing `git pull`, then back off exit out of build, fail deployment and leave that directory tree the same it was before `git pull`.

Comment: Why would there be conflicts? Is your deployment script making local commits and if so why?

Comment: In looking at these responses I think we have overlooked a major difference that distributed source control -- A pull/fetch will grab a whole repository, not just one branch.  You must specify individual branches as shown in a couple of answers below.

Comment: @CBBailey ... When many people are working on many branches (e.g different versions and features) there will often be overlap.  Checking before hand makes it easier to plan your merge and later pull request.  An equivalent command with SVN is: `svn -q -u`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I have always relied on the inherent abilities of Git to get me back if a merge fails.

To estimate how the merge might occur, you can start like you did with:

```
$ git fetch origin branch  # Fetch changes, but don't merge
$ git diff HEAD..origin/branch # Diff your current head to the fetched commit

... personal judgement of potential merge conflicts ...

$ git merge origin/branch # merge with the fetched commit
```

If things did not go as planned, look at your `reflog` and reset back to your desired state:

```
$ git reflog
...
abc987  HEAD@{0}: merge activity
b58aae8 HEAD@{1}: fetch origin/branch
8f3a362 HEAD@{2}: activity before the fetch
...
$ git reset --hard HEAD{2}
```

Comment: You can also try this since pulling is somehow similar to merging [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option)

Comment: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD..origin/branch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: @Green try  git reset --hard HEAD@{2}

Comment: @Green maybe like that: `git diff HEAD..origin/master`

Answer (score 44):

You will need to fetch first to update your local origin/master

```
git fetch origin
```

Then you can do:

```
git diff --name-only origin/master
```

Will list the files that have changed.

```
git diff origin/master directory_foo/file_bar.m
```

Will list the line by line diff of file directory_foo/file_bar.m.

Answer (score 21):

You can get the effect you want by creating a new throw-away branch from your current one and doing the `git pull` there.  If you're unhappy with the results, the original branch is intact.

Comment: you mean `git stash`?

Comment: No , git stash is entirely different. That puts your local changes elsewhere.

Comment: @WesternGun being on the branch You want to copy -  `git checkout -b testBranchName`

Answer (score 19):

```
# fetch new commits from origin
$ git fetch

# check what are the differences and judge if safe to apply
$ git diff origin/master

# actually merge the fetched commits 
$ git pull
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I did a `git diff this-answer/top-answer` and no significant error is found. Please consider leaving a comment when you commit a downvote: `git commit -m "why would you downvote, blah blah blah"`.

Answer (score 16):

Since v2.27.0 there is a [dry-run flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull/2.27.0#Documentation/git-pull.txt---dry-run)

Comment: Right! Since 06/01/20 there is a dry-run flag for pull (but not for merge)

Answer (score 4):

Since pulling implies merging, I'd go with running `git merge --abort` if your script detects there were any conflicts and merging failed.

Comment: If you were doing this against a remote branch (going a `git fetch origin branch` first) it would be `git merge --abort origin/branch` right?

Answer (score 1):

See my answer in this similar question:

[How to preview git-pull without doing fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180272/how-to-preview-git-pull-without-doing-fetch/48784435#48784435)

this goes to the `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
        diffpull=!git fetch && git diff HEAD..@{u}
```

Answer (score 1):

OliverE is spot-on:  `git pull` has a `dry-run` option, so I recommend `git pull --dry-run -v` to achieve the OP's purpose -- simple and direct.  `pull` did not always have a dry-run option but in previous (and current) versions of git, `fetch` did (and does) have a dry-run option.   Thus, an alternative approach is to do a `git fetch --dry-run -v` before you do your pull.  Always better to check on an action before executing it, than having to spend time reverting.

Answer (score 0):

Without pulling:

```
[ "$(git fetch;git diff | wc -l)" != "0" ] && (
echo there are updates
echo do your stuff here
)
```

or without touching anything:

```
[ "$(git pull --dry-run | wc -l)" != "0" ] && (
echo there are updates
echo do your stuff here
)
```