# git pull List all errors

Tags: git, git-pull

I'm trying to do a `git pull` and I'm getting `error: Your local changes to 'someDir/someFile' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.` this is fine since I need to check these changes and decide whether these need committed or not.

However doing the above, checking that file and committing/rolling back is laborious if I have to do it each time. Is there a way I can get `git pull` to list *all* merge errors rather than one each time?

Comment: A very similar question: Is there in git “git pull --dry-run” option? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222440/is-there-in-git-git-pull-dry-run-option). The accepted answer is the answer you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Using `git status -vs` will show you a list of tracked changes.

If you want to store them to deal with after the pull you can use `git stash`, pull your repo, then `git stash pop` to restore the changes. Keep in mind there may be conflicts you have to resolve.

Another way of doing this is don't pull unless you are going to commit the changes you have made. Then just use `git pull --rebase` which will place your commit on top of the pulled commits.