# git status of another remote

Tags: git, status

I added a second remote by issuing:

```
git remote add stash ...
```

However, when I do

```
git status
```

It checks for the status of origin/master. How can I issue a git status to check for the status of the second remote, in this case "stash". I tried the following commands, but they still track origin/master:

```
git status stash/master
git status "stash/master"
```

Thanks in advance for the input!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git status` uses the configured information for the branch in the repository config file ( (repo)/.git/config) to show status.

If you wish to change that, you will need to change what your branch is tracking.  You can do that a variety of ways.  For newer versions of git use

`git branch --set-upstream-to=stash/master`

Note that `stash` is a command in Git, so I would not recommend using it as a name for a remote because it could cause potential confusion.

Comment: For me, this command is working to set the remote "origin" for the specified branch "maven": `git branch maven -u origin/maven`

Answer (score 2):

The comamnd

```
git status
```

gives you the status of the working tree.

If you would like to 'use' the 'stash/master' tree you need to pull it with

```
git pull stash master
```

then the working tree will be pointing to 'stash/master'.

If you want to see what the pull will do before running it see: [How to preview git-pull without doing fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180272/how-to-preview-git-pull-without-doing-fetch)

Addendum:

Look at the link below to see how to get you master branch to follow a different remote.

[Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Comment: I did a "git pull stash master" and it gets the status of it fine, but if I do a "git status" afterwards it still checks the status of origin/master. How can I change the working tree to be the stash remote instead of origin, or have git status check for stash/master instead of  origin/master by default?