# How to test outcome of git pull?

Tags: git, zsh

I would like to test the outcome of `git pull`.

Currently we use this deployment approach:

```
git pull && rake build && rake deploy
```

However it unfortunately does much unnecessary work in the case that the pull is a no-op.

Can this be improved?

Comment: Can you add some detail describing what result you want? What do you mean by pull being a no-op? If `git pull` determines that the current branch is up to date, then it will still succeed and return 0 because no error occurred.

Comment: Searching docs now, But My thought is that `git pull` is actually `git fetch && git merge`.  Maybe do a `git fetch` then compare branches `master` and `origin/master`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The OP wants to find out if anything will / has changed after a `git pull`.

Comment: @PhilipCouling That is my working assumption as well. However, until the OP clarifies, we are only guessing.

Comment: What is usually done for deployment jobs using a CI tool is connecting to the repository and triggering the job just in case of change in the repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preview git-pull without doing fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180272/how-to-preview-git-pull-without-doing-fetch)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's hard to see how this question is unclear.  Line 4 makes it clear the OP's aim is to handle a no-op pull with a lot less work.

Comment: @PhilipCouling It is unclear because we are deducing the desired behavior from the information given rather than the OP stating it explicitly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for the lesson in logic. I think you mean induct, not deduct.

Comment: The only problem I see with running `git fetch` first is the assumption that `master` is checked out. Comparing the current branch with the remote tracking branch seems like a very good way to predict if `git pull` would actually change the current branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's basically two things you can do.  You can interpret the output, or you can interrogate to see if anything has changed.

You haven't specified your shell (windows or a unix shell like bash) so I can't give example code.  But `git pull` will print `Already up-to-date.` if nothing changes.  So skip the build and deploy if that happens.

The second option is to check your commit number before and after using:

```
git rev-list -n 1 HEAD
```

If this changes, then the pull did something, if not then it didn't

Comment: Thank you, good idea. So now we use `git pull|grep -v Already&&rake build deploy`

Answer (score 1):

Use `git log -1 --pretty=format:%H` to get the commit hash *before* and *after* the `git pull`.

Compare both hashes and start a build when they differ.